# Regular expressions in Lua using .gsub()

Tags: regex, string, lua, gsub

Ok, I think I overcomplicated things and now I'm lost. Basically, I need to translate this, from Perl to Lua:

```
my $mem;
my $memfree;
open(FILE, 'proc/meminfo');
while (<FILE>)
{
    if (m/MemTotal/)
    {
        $mem = $_;
        $mem =~ s/.*:(.*)/$1/;
    }

}
close(FILE);
```

So far I've written this:

```
for Line in io.lines("/proc/meminfo") do
    if Line:find("MemTotal") then
        Mem = Line
        Mem = string.gsub(Mem, ".*", ".*", 1)
    end
end
```

But it is obviously wrong. What am I not getting? I understand why it is wrong, and what it is actually doing and why when I do

```
print(Mem)
```

it returns

```
.*
```

but I don't understand what is the proper way to do it. Regular expressions confuse me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua doesn't use regular expressions. See Programming in Lua, sections [20.1](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) and following to understand how pattern matching and replacement works in Lua and where it differs from regular expressions.

In your case you're replacing the complete string (`.*`) by the literal string `.*` – it's no surprise that you're getting just `.*` returned.

The original regular expression replaced anything containing a colon (`.*:(.*)`) by the part after the colon, so a similar statement in Lua might be

```
string.gsub(Mem, ".*:(.*)", "%1")
```

Comment: ok, thank you. It sort of makes sense now, I just think I will never be able to fully comprehend regular expressions.

Comment: The capture group (`(.*)`) is unnecessary. `string.gsub(Mem, ".*:", "")` is enough. It removes everything up to the last `:`.

Comment: @Mizard: I just copied the code verbatim from the Perl code, but indeed this should suffice, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The code below parses the contents of that file and puts it in a table:

```
meminfo={}
for Line in io.lines("/proc/meminfo") do
    local k,v=Line:match("(.-): *(%d+)")
    if k~=nil and v~=nil then meminfo[k]=tonumber(v) end
end
```

You can then just do

```
print(meminfo.MemTotal)
```

Comment: This is a much better and more complete solution.